# Airflow - TriggerDagRunOperator Cross Check

Tags: airflow

I am trying to trigger one dag from another. I am using `TriggerDagRunOperator` for the same.

I have the following two dags.

**Dag 1:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator


def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

dag = DAG('dag_one', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0/15 * * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="test_trigger_dagrun",
    trigger_dag_id="dag_two",  # Ensure this equals the dag_id of the DAG to trigger
    dag=dag,
)


dummy_operator >> hello_operator >> trigger
```

**Dag 2:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_hello():
    return 'Hello XYZABC!'

dag = DAG('dag_two', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

Going through the webserver, everything seems fine and running (ie: dag one is triggering dag two ).
My question is how to make sure or check that Dag 2 is actually triggered by Dag 1 and it is not triggered because of its schedule or any other manual action.
Basically, where I can find who triggered the Dag or how the Dag was triggered?

Answer (score 0):

If you see Tree view of Dag 1, Dag 2 that was run by Dag 1 is seen as tasks in this view.

If you see Tree view of Dag 2, you can find AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=**trig**__YYYY_MM_DD... in View Log.

If this is scheduled, it should say
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=**scheduled**__YYYY_MM_DDT...

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the occurrence time of dag2 with the occurrence time of the triggle task in dag1